# Can you see live trade data on the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, trading

I am reading a lot about quantum trading, and machine learning, and am looking for data sources to train my algorithms. I an curios to see if there is a way to see live exchanges on the bitcoin blockchain? For example if someone is trading bitcoin for ethereum or vice versa on bittrex, how would I go about seeing all of this data on the chain? I know it exists, but not sure where to look.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: No.

Exchanges do not post trades to blockchains, confirmation would take too much time.
Instead they keep funds in their own wallets (often offline) and settle transactions in their systems only using blockchain when a user wants to withdraw cryptocurrency.